# $VIM location wrong on Windows 7

Tags: vim

for some reason my $VIM location on this Windows machine I am using points to `/etc`. Is there a way to change this? I don't know where it would be to change this so it is looking in the correct location. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you believe `/etc` is wrong?

Comment: Check if it is set outside of Vim. Possibly it is, for the sake of cygwin or something.

Comment: If you really need to change it, maybe you could put at the beginning of your `.vimrc` file a line like `let $VIM=[your location]`?

Comment: @Ben - Put this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer. Cygwin had it set up for the convenience of Cygwin instead of having it where I wanted it to be. Thank you

Comment: Sure but now does cygwin's Vim work? I hesitated to put it as an answer in case cygwin set it like that for a reason. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim will use an environment variable for $VIM, if one is defined. Check if you have a %VIM% environment variable defined. If you do, it may have been set by cygwin or a similar program, so be sure any Vim installation in there still works without this variable before removing it permanently.